# After geting data from API , How to display api data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

Here is my code for call API using Fetch URL method, after getting data from API how to display data into HTML table

`index.html`

```
 <body>
        <input type="text" name="daterange" value="" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    opens: 'left'
                }, function (start, end, label) {
                    variable_one = "selected_date: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    console.log("Hai hari its working");
                    console.log(variable_one);
                    fetch("http://localhost:3000/09-12-2021")
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log(data));
                });
            });
            
        </script>
    
    </body>
```

`db.json`
Here is my sample JSON data

```
[
{
"s.no": 1,
"date": "09-12-2021",
"time": "12am",
"videos": "video_01",
"button": "play"
}]
```

How to display data into HTML table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different Object method in js like `Object.keys` and `Object.values` ... you can cycle throgh each values or keys of the object you get from the data array ! ... using this with the power of template strings and DOM manipulation u can achieve what you are looking for .

Example =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>


  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    const thead = document.querySelector("table > thead > tr");
    const tbody = document.querySelector("table > tbody");
    let data = [{
      "s.no": 1,
      "date": "09-12-2021",
      "time": "12am",
      "videos": "video_01",
      "button": "play"
    }];
    
    Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(attr => {
      thead.innerHTML +=
      `<th>${attr}</th>`;
    });
    data.forEach(ele =>{
      let append = "";
      append += "<tr>";
      Object.values(ele).forEach(entry =>{
        append += `<td>${entry}</td>`;
      });
      append += "</tr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += append;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @hari prasath Just after fetching the data you can use the same logic ... It will work fine !

Comment: Thank you so much , How to get json data via url and fetch into HTML table

Comment: @hari prasath you  can use the fetch request and after fetch request is complete you can use the dot (.) then method [remember its a promise ] ... and there you go . Another approach is using modern  async / await methods !